# Updating 3 different TIMESTAMP columns in MYSQL 5.6 table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three columns in my table that needs to be updated separately from my PHP app during three separate events

1. Creation Event
2. Update Event #1
3. Update Event #2.

These events happen in sequence and hence at different `TIMESTAMPS`. When Event #2 happens, `Col-2` updates just fine. However, when Even #3 happens, it updates `Col_3` correctly, but ***also*** overwrites the value of `Col_2` as the same value of `Col_3`, and it should not doing that, leaving `Col_2` to the same value that it had when Event#2 happened.

Can any expert please help me resolve this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Here's how I have defined the columns in the table `callevents`:

```
col_1 : TYPE : TIMESTAMP, DEFAULT= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
col_2 : TYPE : TIMESTAMP, DEFAULT = NULL
col_3 : TYPE : TIMESTAMP, DEFAULT = NULL
```

There is no problem in the update of `callevents-col_1`.

Both events #2 and #3 are handled in the same PHP file.

Event #2 is invoked when the PHP file is loaded and at that time I have

```
$date = new DateTime();
$event_2_when = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$db->updateOne("col_2", $event_2_when, "callid", $_GET["callid"], "callevents");
```

Event #3 is invoked when the user performs a POST on a form on the same page. In that case I have :

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$date = new DateTime();
$event_3_when = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$db->updateOne("col_3", $event_3_when, "callid", $_GET["callid"], "callevents");
}
```

The function updateOne is defined as follows:

```
public function updateOne($fieldName, $fieldVal, $idField, $idVal, $table) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->db, "UPDATE " . $table . " SET " . $fieldName . " = '$fieldVal' WHERE " . $idField . " = '$idVal'");
    if (!$stmt) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $this->db->errno . ") " . $this->db->error;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten to close your quotes in your function call.

Comment: not really :-) - thanks for pointing that out but it was merely a cut-and-paste problem in SO. I have the closing quotes in my actual codebase and I have this problem continuing

Comment: You need to move your code around, check for post at top and add an else to update event 2 only when there isn't a post.  If you think about it your script is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. If you have it update event 2 every page load why are you confused as to why it gets updated when you post to the page?

Comment: OMG @ElefantPhace, you are absolutely right. I followed your instructions and it works like a charm. Thank you so much for your valuable advice - very grateful ...